# Is there a way to trace Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get the following error message in the console :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined

It is a site with tons of code placed by different developers. Is there a way to trace what is causing this error? which function piece of code causing this?

Comment: Double click the error in the console. It will take you to the line of code that caused the error, and may also show you the call stack depending on the browser you're using

Comment: I know that, but this gave me an error on jquery file.... not a particular piece of code. But i have figured it out. the element with a class  was searched by code and it wasn't there. - deleted.. Yeah, too many people on one project  Thanks anyway.

Comment: No problem - although as I mentioned it will take you to the line that threw the error. It will also show you the call stack so you can see which method of your own code called the library.